# Can't correct perspective of Main Camera in Unity 3D without losing field of view

Tags: unity, camera, shooter

I have been trying to create a space based rails shooter game following a particular online course and I find a tilt(roll) on my spaceship as I move it towards the left and right ends of the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/exzDp.jpg
(A normal screenshot of my spaceship at default position)

This is due to perspective of the camera as I have been told and apparently dragging the camera farther behind the spaceship and decreasing its field of view helps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBH8d.jpg
(The tilted spaceship when it's at an end of the game window)

But, doing that neutralizes the illusion of speed caused by a greater field of view. I have found a middle point between the two to balance both aspects of the game but I would like to know if there is any way to get higher field of view without making the ship look like it's tilted.

Things I have considered doing:

1. Added a positionRollFactor which gives the ship some additional roll in the opposite direction of the tilt. (This still doesn't fix the perspective issue in which one half of the ship is more enlarged than the other).
2. Tweaking the field of view by trading off a little of each feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to your problem would be to render your ship with one camera and everything else with another. Both cameras have the same position and rotation. The one rendering everything but your ship has a high FOV. This way your ship will look normal but your environment will be warped.